# Return undefined from existing property in javascript model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a well-defined model, written this way:

```
export class Navigation {
  line: {
    _id: string;
    code: string;
    name: string;
    isVia: boolean;
    _operator: {
      _id: string;
      name: string;
    };
    via: {
      _id: string;
      name: string;
    }
  };
  hour: string;
  destiny: string;
}
```

On a certain page I'm starting in a variable before the constructor and I do so:

```
public navigation: Navigation = new Navigation ();
```

Below in the `constructor` I am doing so:

```
this.navigation.destiny = 'center';
this.navigation.line.isVia = false;
this.navigation.line.via.name = 'No path to this line';
```

I can access the `hour` and`destiny` properties however the property for example line does not work. On my console is giving the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Can not set property 'isVia' of undefined
>   TypeError: Can not set property 'isVia' of undefined

I need to use the model data.

What can be and how to arrange?

**ATTEMPTS**

1. public navigation: Navigation =  {};
2. public navigation: Navigation = new Navigation;
3. public navigation: Navigation; and in the this.navigation = Navigation () constructor;

Both of these occur the same error.

**SCENARIO**

I'm developing in `ionic 2` basically it works with`angular 4` and uses `typescript` as a language. When I create a page in 'ionic 4' it generates files in (`.html`,`.ts`, `.scss`,`.modeule.ts`) the `.ts` file controls my pages, in it I can manipulate easily all my `html`, making requests to the server and changing on the screen at runtime easily. For a better development I use the idea of ​​`models` to standardize my content both receiving and receiving when shipping, based on this everything I receive / sending has the formulation of a`model`. The model is a separate file, in case mine is expressed in its total form (ie every file) in my `.ts` of my page I am instantiating this my model, saying that my`navigation` variable will take the form of my template `Navigation` shortly after my constructor having added a value, for as I informed you about using it in my html. At this moment I am trying the error which I express in this question.

In order to reproduce the error it is necessary to use a `complex` `model`, that is to say that it has objects object, it can be observed in mine that I have values ​​in the root (`destiny`,`hour`) and a `line` object inside this object I have others, I can not access this object from `line` and nothing that has inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is not initialized. Change your model to this:

```
export class Navigation {
  line:any= {
        _id: undefined,
        code: undefined,
        name: undefined,
        isVia: undefined,
        _operator: {
          _id: undefined,
          name: undefined,
        },
        via: {
          _id: undefined,
          name: undefined,
       }
  };
  hour: undefined;
  destiny: undefined;
}
```

Comment: This error appeared
 TS2693:'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Comment: Change your answer to fit what you needed to do. To solve I did this:   line: any = {
    _id: String,
    code: String,
    name: String,
    isVia: Boolean,
    _operator: {
      _id: String,
      name: String,
    },
    via: {
      _id: String,
      name: String,
    }
  };
  hour: String;
  destiny: String;

Comment: yes I realized the mistake. I have updated my answer with undefined values at start, that will do

Comment: In case I would need variable typing then for me it could not be undefined so I set the values ​​to ensure that each variable would have the correct type. But thank you for taking my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign line property first in defining class if you want to set any line property. Initially after `new Navigation()` `line` property is `undefined`. So you have to set something initially on it. And after it you can use props of `line`

```
export class Navigation {
  line: {
    _id: string;
    code: string;
    name: string;
    isVia: boolean;
    _operator: {
      _id: string;
      name: string;
    };
    via: {
     _id: string;
     name: string;
    }
  } = {via: {}, _operator: {}};
  hour: string;
  destiny: string;
}
```

or

```
var nav = new Navigation();
nav.line = {isVia = false, via: {...}};
```

Answer (score 1):

since `line` is an object , it is `undefined` when u construct `Navigation` ,you have to initialize it like that then put the value in `isVia` :

```
this.navigation.destiny = 'center';
this.navigation.line = {}; 
this.navigation.line.isVia = false;
this.navigation.line.via = {}; 
this.navigation.line.via.name = 'No path to this line';
```

Hope it helps